# Primefaces Fileuploader issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.5 components in my JSF projects.If my confirmation dialog is over primefaces fileuploder , fileuploader is still active which is actually below the confirmation dialog and I can select files.How to fix this component bleeding issue.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Here is another same issue. Primefaces Fileuploader is always active even when another modal window is shown above , confirmation dialog in  my cases which itself is modal .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190302/primefaces-fileupload-component-is-still-clickable-while-modal-dialog-is-shown